# Can't access XAMPP on my laptop from my phone

Tags: xampp, android

I have a XAMPP running on Windows on port 8012. When I enter my laptop's IP `192.168.1.101:8012` in my phone's browser(I am using Android), I am getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I have added a new rule in Windwos Firewall for this port to be accessed in any type of network(Private, Public and Domain) but still getting this error.

Any ideas why?